# Linkedin sharing page keeps spinning

Tags: linkedin-api

I’m trying to use the shareArticle API on a website for a client, whatever parameters I’m giving the share page keeps spinning, it seems to be a parsing issue but I’m not able to figure it out.I’ve also tried to use the share button API but it’s not better.

This is the URL I’m trying to share (but every URL from the site seems to be having the same issue) : http://www.urbanem.fr/formation-gestion-conflits-mediation-2/

Any idea what might be wrong?

Here’s the source code to generate the share button:

```
$postURLLinkedin = urlencode(home_url() . "?p=" . get_the_ID());

$linkedin_share = '<li><a class="sb-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url='.$postURLLinkedin.'&amp;title='.urlencode($postTitle).'&amp;source='.urlencode(home_url()).'&amp;summary='.urlencode($postSummary).'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,\'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;" title="Partager sur Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>';
```

Comment: Note that the share dialog doesn't work even while using Linkedin Share Button Generator, which rules out any parsing reason on your behalf https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the url in your linkedin profile and then make sharing works again. It's not the right thing to do but I is saving me yet.
We need a fix for this, as I pass me the same. The link you want to share are created dynamic. The share is loaded and never get to share. With all browsers I have the same problem.

Comment: Gracias Javier, I tested your workaround. It works, though it's not very convenient having to do it for each post. I reported the bug to LinkedIn. Did you start to have this problem recently?

Comment: I started to have problems in my system in November. Before that everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and its working fine. Though I didnt share it, but I was at the last step of sharing.

Comment: Hello @SD, please check my use case: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://blog.pranalog.com/que-es-el-dialogo/ is it working for you? for me it keeps loading

Comment: Yes @lisovaccaro when I click on that link it directly opens an linkedin login view, and once logged into, it opens the sharing view waiting for share button to click. I think you need to check, whether linkedin is enabled at your end? Any restriction while accessing linkedin?

Comment: I don't think so, I tested it on Chrome and Safari, and also 3 different people reported the issue. It's surprising you can get the share dialog, can I ask you what browser are you using? thanks

Comment: let me share a screenshot with you. Check this out; https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByFe7sxlGYPiMzgyemhWbDRNUG8/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @lisovaccaro I have also shared content with my account. Check this. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByFe7sxlGYPiUVY5TS1wcnc4blk/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Still the dialog should have shown the post image and description. I understand that you could share it still a number of people can't. Also the workaround from @JavierG works, while it's not really a good alternative as I can't post every article in LinkedIn manually.

Comment: Image and descriptions are fetched from your page itself by linkedin. You need to avail related contents in proper Structure and linkedin will get those content automatically. Last night I was checking with slow connection, I just tried on my PC and its also sharing images & description too. http://goo.gl/4MMqug

Comment: hi @SD I created a simple page with just a share button to see what might be wrong. Could you please check it out? http://pranalog.com/linkedin-share.php For me the dialog always keeps loading, the same happens in my client's pc. I hope you see something wrong as I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @lisovaccaro I checked with your sample page. It works here. https://docs.google.com/a/hiddenbrains.in/file/d/0BxldY8Ux-hmGcmp2NklTbnBucWM/edit?usp=drivesdk. Can you share your console.log screenshot?

Comment: hi @SD it seems the one you shared fixed for me the moment you shared it, did you share it using the button? Could you please check this last one to see if you can reproduce the issue? http://pranalog.com/linkedin-share1.php this is what I see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9KZr1w4stxPSVVOS2ptMDk3Tzg/view?usp=sharing